# Camel HTTPS Webservice Consumption - HTTP Status Code 500

Tags: java, web-services, https

I am able to successfully negotiate the SSL handshake and after that it fails with HTTP Status Code: 500.

We are using the DataPower to access the secured WS.  I am able to invoke the service through SoapUI and it goes through fine.  It fails when I invoke from Camel.  Our DataPower guys says that they are seeing the response coming back and returned to the application.  Any thoughts, would be greatly appreciated.

org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://xx.x.x.x.x.x:5618/Reservation with statusCode: 500
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:229)[camel-http-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:157)[camel-http-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]